# Drupal form condition to check for submit event

Tags: api, drupal, forms, submit

I have a form with 2 buttons, submit and new. I want different actions to be performed on both cases. How do i differentiate between the 2 events??

Something like

```
if($form_state['submit']['op']){
submit handler code
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the default submit function (formname_submit) and break it out like so:

```
switch($form_state['clicked_button']['#id']) {
    case 'edit-button-name' :
      ...code...
      break;
    case 'edit-button-name1' :
       ...code...
      break;
}
```

Or you can define separate submit functions per button where the form is defined:

```
$form['buttons']['new']['#submit'][] = 'name_of_submit_function';
$form['buttons']['delete']['#submit'][] = 'name_of_submit_function';
```